# Is it safe to drink from Pick A Brick cups?

Tags: pick-a-brick

I have a habit of drinking from the Lego Pick A Brick cups.  I sent an email to Lego to ask if they were rated safe for drinking from, and they refused to endorse any use of Lego products that wasn't originally intended.

They did point out that the bricks were made from ABS, but a PAB cup is not a brick, nor did they say if ABS was rated safe for food use.

Has anyone tested the plastic in the PAB cups to see what they are, or if they are safe for food use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Pick-a-Brick cups are made from polypropylene, as evidenced by the #5 [resin identification code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resin_identification_code) on the bottom. Polypropylene is [widely](http://modernsurvivalblog.com/preps/safe-plastics-for-food-and-drink/) [considered](http://greenerpenny.blogspot.com/2010/04/safest-plastics-for-holding-food.html) a safe plastic for storing food and drink, and it is stable at very high temperatures (i.e., temperatures higher than your dishwasher). I would feel comfortable drinking out of one of the cups.